# How I can get the AspNetWebSocketContext from the current context?

Tags: c#, websocket, .net-4.5

I am implementing ASP.net websocket server using Microsoft webscoket. I have a function which sends data to the client. Below is the class.

```
public class MyWebSocketHandler : IHttpHandler
    {

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (context.IsWebSocketRequest)
            {
                context.AcceptWebSocketRequest(DoTalking);

            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        public async Task DoTalking(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
        {
            WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
            while (true)
            {
                ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
                WebSocketReceiveResult result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None);
                if (socket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
                {
                    string userMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.Array, 0, result.Count);
                    userMessage = "Message from client : " + userMessage;

                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        public async Task SendToClient(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
        {
            WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
            //WebSocket socket = context.WebSocket;
            ArraySegment<byte> buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(new byte[1024]);
            buffer = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message));
            await socket.SendAsync(buffer, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
        }

        public void callSendToClient()
        {
                var task = SendToClient(Problem is here!);
                task.Wait();  
        }

        private string message { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My problem is how to get the AspNetWebSocketContext when I call the SendToClient method ? I am stuck at this point. Actually I want to call SendToClient() method from another .aspx page. Need some help.

Comment: The solution is simple.  You made WebSocketReceiveResult result a local variable inside a method.  Instead declare it as a static variable inside the class.

Comment: @jdweng I didn't get your point. Could you give me an example?

Comment: static WebSocketReceiveResult result = null;
public async Task DoTalking(AspNetWebSocketContext context)
{
   result = await socket.ReceiveAsync(buffer, CancellationToken.None)
}

Comment: @jdweng Thank you!